# How should I connect the RX and TX pins of an Arduino to a Bluetooth module?

Tags: arduino, relay, home-automation, hc-05

[image]

I am working on an Arduino based Bluetooth controlled home automation using a mobile app.

When I power ON the circuit, it works fine but when I power it OFF and power it ON again I have to remove the RX and TX pins and reconnect them to make the circuit.

What is wrong?

Comment: That is a wiring diagram.  Schematic diagrams are more useful when discussing electronic circuits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the  SoftwareSerial library that replicates the serial protocol on any of the PWM pins on the Arduino Uno.

I am guessing you are using the USB to power up Arduino.  This is not going to work with your Bluetooth module because it is connected to RX and TX pins on the Arduino. The RX and TX pins are used for USB communication and hence should only be used when you are not using the serial terminal on the Arduino IDE.